# Problem with HTTP Post in Android

Tags: html, android, http, post, httpclient

I'm getting a problem making an HTTP POST in Android.

The problem occur when the code is reading the response, it cant obtain the complete web page code I want to retrieve.

I only retrieve a piece of the web.

Here is the code:

```
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "06092010"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 

        HttpResponse response; 
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));


        String  s = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while(line != null){
            s += line+"\n";
            line = reader.readLine();
        }


        Log.d("Street", "Result: "+s);          


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block          
        Log.d("Street", e.toString());   
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block          
        Log.d("Street", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Street", e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code I get the same result, but now I know the problem.

The problem isnt it the code, is the Android LogCat (a Logger) where I print the resulting string. In this logger if the string is too long it only shows a short piece of the result.

So the problem was the way that the logger of android shows the longs strings

Thanks Gaz for the help!

Comment: Please mark this as answered then, use this post as the answer. Help keep StackOverflow tidy!

Answer (score 0):

So reader.readLine is returning null before you have reached the end of the stream? Does the buffer contain a newline at the end? [The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) suggest that the end of the stream does not constitute an "end of line":

> Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

I use this approach myself, it works, but is not a very efficient solution:

```
public static String URLToString(URL url) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = (InputStream) url.getContent();
    int ch;

    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    while( ( ch = in.read() ) != -1 ){
        b.append( (char)ch );
    }

    return b.toString();
}
```